# Researching efficient searching of text inside a directory and its subdirectories using C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, batch-file

I am trying to search for a particular occurrence of a string in some files belonging to a directory. (The search is also performed in the sub directories. Currently, I came up with a solution something like this.

1. Get all filenames inside a directory and its sub directories.
2. Open files one by one.
3. Search for a particular string
4. If it contains, store filename in an array.
5. Continue this till the last file.

   ```
   string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(@"d:\test", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
   foreach (string sTem in fileNames)
   {
       foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(sTem))
       {
           if (line.Contains(SearchString))
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Found search string!");
               break;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

I think there can be other methods/approach efficient and speeder than this? Using a batch file? OK. Another, solution is to use findstr (but how to use it directly with C# program without a batch file ? What is the most efficient (or more efficient than what I did?)
Code examples are much appreciated!

Found out another solution.

```
Process myproc = new Process();
myproc.StartInfo.FileName = "findstr";
myproc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/m /s /d:\"c:\\REQs\" \"madhuresh\" *.req";
myproc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
myproc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;


myproc.Start();
string output = myproc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
myproc.WaitForExit();
```

Is this execution of a process good ? Comments on this too are welcome!

According to the @AbitChev's method, a sleek (I don't know if it's efficient!). Anyways, it goes on like this. This one searches all the directory as well as the subdirectories!

```
IEnumerable<string> s = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles("c:\\directorypath", "*.req", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                   from str in File.ReadLines(file)
                   //where str.Contains("Text@tosearched2")
                   where str.IndexOf(sSearchItem, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
                   select file;

        foreach (string sa in s)
            MessageBox.Show(sa);
```

(for case-insensitive search. Maybe that could help someone.)
Please comment! Thanks.

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines` loads the whole file into memory, as long as it fits.

Comment: Yes I know that Jodrell. So, whats the next available way ? an efficient way ofcourse!

Comment: Also you can download and run [Win32 port of GNU Grep](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about somthing like this

```
var found = false;
string file;

foreach (file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(
            "d:\\tes\\",
            "*.txt",
            SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(file))
    {
        if (line.Contains(searchString))
        {
            found = ture;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (found)
    {
            break;
    }
}

if (found)
{
    var message = string.Format("Search string found in \"{0}\".", file)
    MessageBox.Show(file);
}
```

This has the advantage of loading only what is required into memory, rather than the names of all the files then, the contents of each file.

---

I note you are using [`String.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) which

> performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) comparison

This would allow us to do a simple charachter wise compare.

I'd start with a little helper function

```
private static bool CompareCharBuffers(
    char[] buffer,
    int headPosition,
    char[] stringChars)
{
    // null checking and length comparison ommitted

    var same = true;
    var bufferPos = headPosition;
    for (var i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!stringChars[i].Equals(buffer[bufferPos]))
        {
            same = false;
            break;
        }

        bufferPos = ++bufferPos % (buffer.Length - 1);
    }

    return same;
}
```

Then I'd alter the previous algorithm to use the function like this.

```
var stringChars = searchString.ToCharArray();
var found = false;
string file;


foreach (file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(
            "d:\\tes\\",
            "*.txt",
            SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    using (var reader = File.OpenText(file))
    {
        var buffer = new char[stringChars.Length];
        if (reader.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length - 1) 
                < stringChars.Length - 1)
        {
            continue;
        }

        var head = 0;
        var nextPos = buffer.Length - 1;
        var nextChar = reader.Read();
        while (nextChar != -1)
        {
            buffer[nextPos] = (char)nextChar;

            if (CompareCharBuffers(buffer, head, stringChars))
            {
               found = ture;
               break;
            }

            head = ++head % (buffer.Length - 1);
            if (head == 0)
            {
                nextPos = buffer.Length - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                nextPos = head - 1;
            } 

            nextChar = reader.Read();
        }

        if (found)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (found)
{
    var message = string.Format("Search string found in \"{0}\".", file)
    MessageBox.Show(file);
}
```

this holds only as many `char`s as the search string contains in memory and uses rolling buffer across each file. Theoretically the file could contain no new lines and consume your whole disk, or, your search string could contain a new line.

---

As further work I'd convert the per file part of the algorithm into a function and investigate a multi-threaded approach.

So this would be the internal function,

```
static bool FileContains(string file, char[] stringChars)
{
    using (var reader = File.OpenText(file))
    {
        var buffer = new char[stringChars.Length];
        if (reader.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length - 1) 
                < stringChars.Length - 1)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var head = 0;
        var nextPos = buffer.Length - 1;
        var nextChar = reader.Read();
        while (nextChar != -1)
        {
            buffer[nextPos] = (char)nextChar;

            if (CompareCharBuffers(buffer, head, stringChars))
            {
               return true;
            }

            head = ++head % (buffer.Length - 1);
            if (head == 0)
            {
                nextPos = buffer.Length - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                nextPos = head - 1;
            } 

            nextChar = reader.Read();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you could process the files in parallel like this

```
var stringChars = searchString.ToCharArray();

if (Directory.EnumerateFiles(
            "d:\\tes\\",
            "*.txt",
            SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .AsParallel()
    .Any(file => FileContains(file, stringChars)))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Found search string!");
}
```

Comment: Seems good! Loading only what is required to memory! has some advanta

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. I've added a bit about multi-threading

Comment: `AsParallel()` is a great finding!

Answer (score 3):

Use `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` and `File.ReadLines()` - both provides lazy loading of data:

```
from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)
from arr in File.ReadLines(file)
from str in arr
where str.Contains(pattern)
select new 
{
    FileName = file, // file containing matched string
    Line = str // matched string
};
```

or

```
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).AsParallel())
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var arr in File.ReadLines(file).AsParallel())
        {
            // one more try here?
            foreach (var str in arr)
            {
                if (str.Contains(pattern))
                {
                    yield return new 
                    {
                        FileName = file, // file containing matched string
                        Line = str // matched string
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SecurityException)
    {
        // swallow or log
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Abatish. But, str is in format of IEnumerable. Sorry to ask this.I am a newbie. How about converting it in to a string or string array ?

Comment: @AbatishChev.. a little edit in your code. It has to be select file;

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed: Sure, no problem, take a look at my new edit: you actually can select both. Also you can create a type to hold this information and return a collection of it from a searching method.

Comment: ReadLines is a good approach in most cases (and what I'd go for) but a problem for large files without new lines or search strings containing new lines.

Comment: Yes @Jodrell. I agree to that. How about a design using your code (reading line by line and comparing) with Abatish's for an efficient way ?

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed: I'd recommend to extend my query with `AsParallel()` as Jodrell has proposed. That will really improve the final code.

Comment: @abatishchev : Yes, I have browsed for that and learnt that It increases performance for 2 x times. But, Where to add that in your code? I tried adding in Select File.Asparallel() . But it shows me error.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed: `Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).AsParallel()` will enumerate directories in parallel. `File.ReadLines(file).AsParallel()` will enumerate lines in parallel.

Comment: @abatishchev: Hey one sec. If I try to access a file whose access is denied, I get an exception. Using try catch also never helps. Can you modify the code to handle exceptions like in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

This works well.  I searched around 500 terms over 230 files in under .5 milliseconds.  This is very memory intensive; it loads every file into memory

```
public class FindInDirectory
{
    public class Match
    {
        public string Pattern { get; set; }
        public string Directory { get; set; }
        public MatchCollection Matches { get; set; }
    }

    public static List<FindInDirectory.Match> Search(string directory, string searchPattern, List<string> patterns)
    {
        //find all file locations
        IEnumerable<string> files = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, searchPattern, System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        //load all text into memory for MULTI-PATERN
        //this greatly increases speed, but it requires a ton of memory!
        Dictionary<string, string> contents = files.ToDictionary(f => f, f => System.IO.File.ReadAllText(f));

        List<FindInDirectory.Match> directoryMatches = new List<Match>();

        foreach (string pattern in patterns)
        {
            directoryMatches.AddRange
            (
                contents.Select(c => new Match
                {
                    Pattern = pattern,
                    Directory = c.Key,
                    Matches = Regex.Matches(c.Value, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline)
                })
                .Where(c => c.Matches.Count > 0)//switch to > 1 when program directory is same or child of search
            );
        };

        return directoryMatches;
    }

}
```

USE:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> patterns = new List<string>
        {
            "class",
            "foreach",
            "main",
        };
        string searchPattern = "*.cs";
        string directory = "C:\\SearchDirectory";

        DateTime start = DateTime.UtcNow;

        FindInDirectory.Search(directory, searchPattern, patterns);

        Console.WriteLine((DateTime.UtcNow - start).TotalMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "Pipeline" with `Tasks.Dataflow` (this .dll isn't currently part of .NET 4.5, but you can download it from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/gg585582.aspx)) to consume all files and searching for explicit strings. Take a look at this [Reference Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228604.aspx).

Comment: note that this approach isn't really "file searching/reading" specific, but you can build a nice solution that runs several tasks in a cascading style. searching for files refers to reading files refers to store files in your favorite collection type.